# DAX RANKX: Why does it return 1?

Tags: powerbi, dax, rank

I am using AdventureWorks DB and I want to rank the resellers by their total sale amount. So basically the table looks like this:

[image]

I used the following measure to rank it:

```
Rank Reseller = RANKX(ALL(ResellerSales), MAX(ResellerSales[SalesAmount]),,1)
```

But it returns only 1 as the rank.

[image]

I followed these two videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z2qzJVeYhTY

and

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SsZseKOgrWQ&t=603s

but I can't understand what is wrong!

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the current scope that Rankx evaluates de Aggregation.

Try wrapping your aggregation with CALCULATE, and you probably want the SUM not the MAX:

```
Rank Reseller = RANKX(ALL(ResellerSales), CALCULATE(SUM(ResellerSales[SalesAmount])))
```

You can create a Measure like so, and use it on RANKX, since it is a measure it will work without explicitly adding the CALCULATE:

```
Sales Amount = SUM(ResellerSales[SalesAmount])

Rank Reseller = RANKX(ALL(ResellerSales), [Sales Amount])
```

EDIT:

```
Rank Reseller = RANKX(ALL('ResellerSales'[Resellerkey]), [Sales Amount])
```

Try it like this.

Comment: @mixix
Well, it seems that your guidance kind of help. Now, we have rankings that doesn't make any sense :))
For instance, we have a lot of ones, 3s and 14s, but no 2, or 6...

Answer (score 0):

To rank the [ReSellerkey] by [SalesAmount] you'd want to do something like this:

```
Rank Sales Amount := 
    RANKX(
        'Table',
        'Table'[SalesAmount],
        ,
        ASC,
        Dense
        )
```

Comment: @ Steliok

This can not be correct, because:
"A single value for column 'SalesAmount' in table 'Table' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result."

Comment: @Elahe.Meydani is sales amount a measure or a column?